# How to control access to a resource based on an id in path in Dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

I have a Dropwizard application where I have a User resource that I want to allow non-admin users access to only their own data. I also want to allow "admins" access to any user's data.

```
@GET
@Path("/users/{userId}")
@RolesAllowed(value="admin")
public Response getUser(@Auth final Client client, @PathParam("userId") final String userId)
        throws InterruptedException {
    return userDAO.getUser(userId);
}
```

I have implemented Dropwizard's `Authorizer<Principal>` interface and this at least authorizes Users with the "admin" role to access the resource.

```
@Override
public boolean authorize(Principal principal, String allowedRolesForResource) {
    Set<Roles> userRoles = ((Client) principal).getRoles();
    String userId = ((Client) principal).getUserId();

    // Create set of all the allowed roles for the resource
    Set<Roles> allowedRoles = Arrays.asList(allowedRolesForResource.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
            .stream()
            .map(Roles::fromName)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    if(Collections.disjoint(userRoles, allowedRoles)) {
        LOGGER.info("User {} does not have any of the allowed roles [{}] for the resource", userId, allowedRolesForResource);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how I can authorize a non-admin user to access the resource only for their own userId. I have the individual's userId in the scope of the `authorize` method, however I don't have the resource path that is being requested, i.e. /users/123.

Is there a way to get the request context into the scope of my Authorizer class so that I can grant access based on the requested resource path and the user's id?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a path for admin and one for everyone

```
@GET
@Path("/users/{userId}")
@RolesAllowed(value="admin")
public Response getUser(@Auth final Client client, @PathParam("userId") final String userId)
        throws InterruptedException {
    return userDAO.getUser(userId);
}


@GET
@Path("/user")
public Response getUser(@Auth final Client client)
        throws InterruptedException {
    return userDAO.getUser(client.getUserId());
}
```